# When does boost::lexical_cast to std::string fail?

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

I'm writing unit tests and trying to have all my code covered.

I have in my code something like this:

```
template<typename ValueType>
std::string ConvertToStringUsingBoost(ValueType const& v)
{
    try 
    {
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string, ValueType>(v);
    }
    catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast const& e)
    {
        LOG_ERR("Fail to cast %s to string", e.source_type().name);
        return std::string();
    }
}
```

I was reading [these docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/) and couldn't find any information about when `boost::lexical_cast` to `std::string` can throw an exception.

Can you please help me with that?

If it's impossible I'll simply delete this try-catch. If it's possible, I'd prefer to cover this in unit testing.

Comment: You probably could use `boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert` function to of avoid throwing `bad_lexical_cast` exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can fail for example if a **user-defined** conversion throws:

```
enum class MyType {};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, MyType const& )
{
    throw "error";
}

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        boost::lexical_cast< std::string >( MyType{} );
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "lexical_cast exception";
    }
}
```

As you have no control about the type of exceptions thrown by user-defined conversions, catching `boost::bad_lexical_cast` won't even be enough. Your unit test has to catch all exceptions.

[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/a9T5A3vmgc201nv2)

Comment: mmm I read the question as being about bad_lexical_cast specifically but this is a good point

Comment: In the OPs code, he specificly only catches `boost::bad_lexical_cast`

Comment: @darune Question title and description are generic though: "when boost::lexical_cast to std::string can throw an exception". OP didn't ask when it can throw `boost::bad_lexical_cast`. A code sample only accompanies a question and it can be wrong.

Answer (score 10):

I can't think of any reason for lexical cast to string to throw `bad_lexical_cast`, except with user-defined types. If the `ValueType` stream insertion operator can set an error flag on the stream then that's going to result in a `bad_lexical_cast`. Otherwise, not.

Personally I'd keep the `catch` in, even if you're just converting built-ins like `int`s; it doesn't hurt, and may catch bugs if you change the `lexical_cast` in some manner, or if there's some edge case that neither you nor I has considered; if you're not handling the resulting exception, you'll get an abort at runtime!

If you're concerned about the overhead of an exception, you can use [`try_lexical_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.try_lexical_convert) instead and check that it returns `true` rather than catching. However, if the `ValueType` stream insertion operator can throw then you'd still need to be able to catch that exception anyway.

Comment: I always get `bad_weather_cast` whenever I go outside.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Switch to `overcast` for expected behaviour

Comment: Since there is a `catch`, adding `noexcept` specifier to the function can make the calling code smaller/faster.

Comment: Indeed, looking at the boost source where `bad_lexical_cast` is an expected result as in the file `lexical_cast_empty_input_test.cpp` - when converting to a string an empty string is expected.  Couldn't find an instance of to-string conversion throwing.

Answer (score 1):

The only safe and **futureproof** (eg. no nasty surprises after an update of [boost](/questions/tagged/boost)) is to impair your code with something (ugly) like this:

```
template<typename ValueType>
std::string ConvertToStringUsingBoost(ValueType const& v)
{
    try 
    {

#ifdef UNITTEST
      if (unittest == case_fail) {
        throw boost::bad_lexical_cast();
      }
#endif
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string, ValueType>(v);
    }
    catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast const& e)
    {
        LOG_ERR("Fail to cast %s to string", e.source_type().name);
        return std::string();
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to get to that ~100% code coverage !

Comment: Not valid syntax

Comment: true, it was mostly the concept i was aiming at.